# Error with inheritance in python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, pygame

i'm doing an UNO game using Pygame, i'm doing it with lists of cards and classes of each color, when I tried to test the inheritance for using the color class, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    x=example()
  File "C:/Users/Tamara/Desktop/TEC/UNO/UNOclases.py", line 93, in __init__
    Red.__init__(self,Redlist)
TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with Red instance as first argument (got example instance instead)
```

Here's the code (don't mind if one of the names is wrong written, I had to translate it from spanish):

```
class Red:

    def setSpecialRedCards(self):

        self.__Redlist.append(self.__steal2)
        self.__Redlist.append(self.__steal2)
        self.__Redlist.append(self.__Reverse)
        self.__Redlist.append(self.__Reverse)
        self.__Redlist.append(self.__Jump)
        self.__Redlist.append(self.__Jump)

    def setRedNumers (self, number,counter):
        while counter<=9:
            if numero!=0:
                self.__Redlist.append(number)
                self.__Redlist.append(number)
            else:
                self.__listaRoja.append(number)
            number+=1
            counter+=1

    def getRed(self):
        return self.__Redlist

    def __init__(self, Redlist=[]):
        self.__Redlist=Redlist
        self.__number0 = "red 0"
        self.__steal2 = "steal2"
        self.__Reverse = "Reverse"
        self.__jump = "jump"


class example:

    def __init__(self, Redlist=[]):
        Red.__init__(self,Redlist)

    def example2(self):
        return Red.__number0
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class `example` doesn't inherit from class `Red`.

Write

```
class example(Red):
    ....
```

Comment: I had to edit the variable names that were in spanish, otherwise not a lot of people would've understood, and I would have gotten little to no response at all

Comment: If you do that, then produce a traceback with that edited code. Having tracebacks not matching the code is hard. And I don't think programmers are beyond abstracting simple classnames. I don't care if something is called Roja or Red.